# How do I get a cell on Sheet 2 to reference a cell on Sheet 1?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have an Employee database in Excel 10 with several sheets.

I want to change  one column in sheet 1 based on another column in sheet 2.

```
sheet 1                      Sheet 2
Column A, Column B           Column a,  Column b
MHO101      E                MHO101      E1
```

Now I want to sheet1 column b should show automatically E1 when we enter column b in sheet 2

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this have to look for the `MH0101` before finding the value of `E1`? Or is the column A value irrelevant?

Comment: Where does the initial E in sheet 1 column B come from?

Comment: yes, we have to look for Employee code i.e. MHO101 then to update the value of column b in sheet 1.                                             we enter the value in sheet 1 i.e. our master file after performace apprisal we enter sheet 2. any change in column b in sheet 2 should updated on sheet 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can point a specific cell from a sheet to have the value of another cell from another sheet by typing the following in the cell you want to be changed.

```
=[SHEET NAME]![CELL]
```

in your case, let's say that the string "E1" is in cell B1 from "Sheet 2" and you want cell B1 from "Sheet 1" to equals the value of B1 from "Sheet 2". You have to type in

```
=Sheet2!B1
```

into the formula bar of your B1 cell in "Sheet1".

Answer (score 0):

On **Sheet 1 B1** put a formula referencing to **Sheet2 B1**:

```
=Sheet2!B1
```

Answer (score 0):

On `Sheet1` you can use [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/VLOOKUP-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) in column B to find the matching employee code on `Sheet2`.

> VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])

Try this in cell `B1` on Sheet1;

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A1:B1,2,FALSE)
```

This looks for the value of cell `A1` in the table array `Sheet2!A1:B1`. When it finds it, it returns the value of the 2nd column of the array. Your array will be the range of your table on Sheet2. With the example you gave above, it will result in a value of `E1` in cell `B1` of `Sheet1`.